# How to get same grouping result using data.table comparing to the sqldf?

Tags: sql, r, data.table, sqldf

I try to implement SQL query using sqldf and data.table.
I need to do this separately using these 2 different libraries.
Unfortunately, I cannot produce the same result using data.table.

```
library(sqldf)
library(data.table)

Id       <- c(1,2,3,4)
HasPet   <- c(0,0,1,1)
Age      <- c(20,1,14,10)

Posts <- data.table(Id, HasPet, Age)

# sqldf way
ref <- sqldf("
      SELECT Id, HasPet, MAX(Age) AS MaxAge
      FROM Posts
      GROUP BY HasPet
  ")

# data.table way
res <- Posts[,
      list(Id, HasPet, MaxAge=max(Age)),
      by=list(HasPet)]

head(ref)
head(res)
```

Output for sqldf is:

```
> head(ref)
  Id HasPet MaxAge
1  1      0     20
2  3      1     14
```

while the output for data.table is different:

```
> head(res)
   HasPet Id HasPet MaxAge
1:      0  1      0     20
2:      0  2      0     20
3:      1  3      1     14
4:      1  4      1     14
```

Please note, that SQL query cannot be modified.

Comment: The GROUP BY query is invalid and expected to raise an exception.

Comment: A tibble? This is not the output of `data.table`.

Comment: @jarlh This SQL query was given on some R courses. It seems to me that this is correct. Anyway, it works well with sqldf.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Now class(res) prints [1] "data.table" "data.frame".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes up a lot with data.table. If you want the max or min by group, the best way is a self-join. It's fast, and only a little arcane.

You can build it up step by step:
In data.table, you can select in i, do in j, and group afterwards. So first step is to find the thing we want within each level of the group

```
Posts[, Age == max(Age), by = HasPet]
#    HasPet    V1
# 1:      0  TRUE
# 2:      0 FALSE
# 3:      1  TRUE
# 4:      1 FALSE
```

We can use `.I` to retrieve the integer vector per row, then what was previously the V1 logical vector TRUE and FALSE indexes within each group so we have only the row containing the max per group.

```
Posts[, .I[Age == max(Age)], by=HasPet]

# From the data.table special symbols help:
# .I is an integer vector equal to seq_len(nrow(x)). While grouping,
# it holds for each item in the group, its row location in x. This is useful
# to subset in j; e.g. DT[, .I[which.max(somecol)], by=grp].

#    HasPet V1
# 1:      0  1
# 2:      1  3
```

We then use the column V1 that we just made in order to call the specific rows (1 and 3) from the data.table. That's it!

```
Posts[Posts[, .I[Age == max(Age)], by=HasPet]$V1]
```

Comment: Could you please rewrite in more explicit form? It would be more valueable for community members, imho.

Comment: BTW, thank you for your answer! How about: GroupedByHasPet <- Posts[,
                 list(Id,
                      HasPet,
                      MaxAge = max(Age),
                      IsMaxAge=(Age == max(Age))
                      ),
                 by=HasPet]
Posts[GroupedByHasPet$IsMaxAge]. It is your answer but a little bit rewritten. If you don't mind, should you use this (or similar) version instead?

Comment: Few notes: You can replace `list` by `.` in data.table. When you assign with `<-` you are not creating a deep copy, which can cause problems if you change things in GroupedByHasPet and they change unexpectedly in Posts. Generally speaking, I've found that if I can avoid creating new data.tables, I encounter fewer unexpected surprises. It's useful for figuring out what you're doing in the beginning to split it out, but performant code with data.table will usually want to avoid these steps. If it doesn't matter, it doesn't matter, of course! Then only the modification by reference part matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.SD` to get subset of rows for each value of `HasPet`.

```
library(data.table)
Posts[, .SD[Age==max(Age)], HasPet]

#   HasPet Id Age
#1:      0  1  20
#2:      1  3  14
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. However, it looks very similar to the solution, given by Danielle McCool. Just to satisfy my curiosity I've microbenchmarked these 2 similar solutions. I thought that your version will be faster. Instead, it was found that it was a little bit slower.

Comment: At least for the moment, .SD is clearer, but less efficient by quite a bit.
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4886